# What's the best way to "periodically" replace characters in a string in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, replace

I have a string where a character ('@') needs to be replaced by characters from a list of one or more characters "in order" and "periodically".
So for example I have

`'ab@cde@@fghi@jk@lmno@@@p@qrs@tuvwxy@z'`

and want

`'ab1cde23fghi1jk2lmno312p3qrs1tuvwxy2z'`

for `replace_chars = ['1', '2', '3']`

The problem is that in this example there are more @ in the string
than I have replacers.

This is my try:

```
result = ''
replace_chars = ['1', '2', '3']
string = 'ab@cde@@fghi@jk@lmno@@@p@qrs@tuvwxy@z'

i = 0
for char in string:
    if char == '@':
        result += replace_chars[i]
        i += 1
    else:
        result += char

print(result)
```

but this only works of course if there are not more than three @ in the original string and otherwise I get **IndexError**.

Edit: Thanks for the answers!

Comment: use `replace_chars[i % replace_chars.length]`. then you only do up to "modulo" of the lengh in index. e.g. with 3 chars, you do `1 % 3 -> 1`, `2 % 3 -> 2`, `3 % 3 -> 0`, `4 % 3 -> 1`, etc...

Comment: Add `i %= 3`  below `i+=1`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your code could be fixed by adding the line `i = i%len(replace_chars)` as the last line of your `if` clause. This way you will be taking the remainder from the division of `i` by the length of your list of replacement characters.

The shorter solution is to use a generator that periodically spits out replacement characters.

```
>>> from itertools import cycle
>>> s = 'ab@cde@@fghi@jk@lmno@@@p@qrs@tuvwxy@z'
>>> replace_chars = ['1', '2', '3']
>>>
>>> replacer = cycle(replace_chars)
>>> ''.join([next(replacer) if c == '@' else c for c in s])
'ab1cde23fghi1jk2lmno312p3qrs1tuvwxy2z'
```

For each character `c` in your string `s`, we get the next replacement character from the `replacer` generator if the character is an `'@'`, otherwise it just gives you the original character.

For an explanation why I used a list comprehension instead of a generator expression, read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9060653/list-comprehension-without-python/9061024#9061024).

Answer (score 6):

Generators are fun.

```
def gen():
    replace_chars = ['1', '2', '3']
    while True:
        for rc in replace_chars:
            yield rc

with gen() as g:
    s = 'ab@cde@@fghi@jk@lmno@@@p@qrs@tuvwxy@z'
    s = ''.join(next(g) if c == '@' else c for c in s)
```

As PM 2Ring suggested, this is functionally the same as `itertools.cycle`. The difference is that `itertools.cycle` will hold an extra copy of the list in memory which may not be necessary.

`itertools.cycle` source:

```
def cycle(iterable):
    saved = []
    for element in iterable:
        yield element
        saved.append(element)
    while saved:
        for element in saved:
              yield element
```

Comment: Your `gen` is essentially what `itertools.cycle` does.

Comment: Right. Typically, even if there is a useful tool in a standard package, I like to write the native equivalent simply for readability. The assumption being one does not know of the aforementioned tool. Often times, it merely gives you a better understanding. If you want to use `itertools.cycle`, definitely do it.

Comment: @PM2Ring `cycle` also saves the elements from the given iterable, because the iterable might be an iterator that can be exhausted - but if `replace_chars` is guaranteed to be a list, @Goodies generator should work fine.

Comment: Certainly! And I've done the same thing myself when I want to cycle over a list / tuple / string. Sometimes, it *is* worthwhile reinventing the <s>cycle</s> wheel. :)

Comment: `itertools.cycle` will hold an extra copy of the list in memory. <- A shallow copy, of course, i.e. it is just saving references to the values in another list

Answer (score 1):

You could also keep your index logic once you use modulo, using a list comp by using `itertools.count` to keep track of where you are:

```
from itertools import count

cn, ln = count(), len(replace_chars)

print("".join([replace_chars[next(cn) % ln] if c == "@" else c for c in string]))

ab1cde23fghi1jk2lmno312p3qrs1tuvwxy2z
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it is better to not iterate character-by-character, especially for long string with lengthy parts without `@`.

```
from itertools import cycle, chain

s = 'ab@cde@@fghi@jk@lmno@@@p@qrs@tuvwxy@z'
replace_chars = ['1', '2', '3']
result = ''.join(chain.from_iterable(zip(s.split('@'), cycle(replace_chars))))[:-1]
```

I don't know how to efficiently kill last char `[:-1]`.